# Debugger Issue with Delphi 11.3 - Incorrect Evaluation of Breakpoint Results

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

After migrating our project from Delphi 10 to Delphi 11.3, we are experiencing a critical issue with the debugger functionality. The debugger is unable to correctly evaluate and display the result values when breakpoints are set.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Migrate a project from Delphi 10 to Delphi 11.3.
- Set a breakpoint on a function that returns a result, e.g., idx := IndexText('3', ['1', '2', '3']);.
- Run the code in the Delphi 11.3 IDE.
- Attempt to evaluate the return value of the function where the breakpoint is set, either by using a Watch or by hovering the mouse cursor over the function.

```
program DelphiStrings;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  strutils;

var idx : integer;
begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    idx := IndexText('3',['1', '2', '3']);
    WriteLn( idx.ToString);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

[IDE screenshot and the incorrect return value of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JhDJ.png)

The debugger should correctly display the return value of the function at the breakpoint.

Actual Result:
The debugger displays random large integer numbers instead of the correct return value. This issue has been replicated on two different machines.

Comment: If this is true, it sounds like something that should be reported to EMBT in a bug report. I'm not sure what you think SO users can do about it.

Comment: When I try it, the Watch window shows "Inaccessible value".  Hovering over the function fails to show a value.  When I tried it in the evaluator (like your screenshot) it said "Expression illegal in evaluator".  Then I switched to 64-bit, and got the same result in the Watch window and hovering, but in the evaluator I got a large number, as you did.

Comment: This is known issue. There is nothing you or we can do here [https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24190](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24190)